# Mikrotik & Bluetooth coexistence

Tags: router, wireless-router, bluetooth, mikrotik-routeros

I'm having some issues with my bluetooth devices when wifi is running, especially when it's busy doing a backup.

I solved this on my old router with a mode called "bluetooth coexistence" in tomato on a Linksys WRT54GL.

Now I've switched over to a Mikrotik 751G-2HnD and it's absolutely fantastic except that I can't find a bluetooth coexistence mode.  Does anyone know if such a mode is supported or can be enabled for Mikrotik hardware?

Answer (score 0):

As I know in 802.11 itself no such thing "bluetooth coexistence". It can be implemented in bluetooth, or in devices with both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth (to interleave using interfaces).
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/Bluetooth-coexistence

Comment: Actually it apparently is an 802.11 feature where a flag in the SSID tells bluetooth devices which frequencies to avoid.  But the bluetooth needs to cooperate.  Some Wifi points also detect bluetooth devices and share the frequency to avoid conflicts apparently.  They do that with other wifi devices already.  When I enabled it in tomato it helped tremendously.

Comment: Hard to find technical details about it. Look this (http://www.oaultimate.com/networking/reduce-wireless-collisions-for-dd-wrt-and-openwrt.html). As I understand this is try to limit time occupied by one 802.11 transmission. May be it good idea.

Comment: I search in sources. And only found Bluetooth coexistence related to BT and Wi-Fi in same device.